# How can I display a variable number of items using radio buttons in HTML?

Tags: php, html, json, radio-button

**file.json:** {"items":[{"num":1,"color":"red"},{"num":2,"color":"blue"}]}

**Objective:** Read file.json using PHP and delete the objects from the array and save.

**Method:** I am reading the file and displaying the array items alongside radio buttons. Objects corresponding to the selected radio button are deleted.

**Code:**

```
<?php

$myfile = fopen("/home/user/php/".$filename,"r" ) or die("unable to open file");
$myjsonstr = fread($myfile, filesize("/home/user/php/".$filename));
fclose($myfile);

$jsons = json_decode($myjsonstr, true);

?>

<form action="delete.php" method="POST">
    <input type="radio" name="testcase" value="1"> <?php print_r($jsons["testcases"][0]);?>
    <input type="radio" name="testcase" value="2"> <?php print_r($jsons["testcases"][1]);?>
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete Selected Values" />
</form>
```

**Problem:** I need to make my list dynamic in length because the value field of "items" can have variable number of objects. But it seems like number of radio buttons in HTML cannot be variable. As you can see from the code snippet, The no. of radio buttons is always 2. I'll have to change the code if the array in my JSON had 3 objects instead of 2.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: Sorry - welcome prime_mover! -- If you're in PHP already, then use PHP to generate the radio buttons. PHP can easily be used to create an arbitrary selection of html. That's all done server side. The html doesn't change on the client side (though it could, with javascript, for example). It is created server side, dynamically as it were, and arrives complete and correct.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not sure if I get what you said. This is my first time doing PHP and HTML. I would be really grateful if you could show me an example to illustrate what you said or maybe link to a source.

Comment: I hate to do so much, when you have shown so little. Meaning, what code have you already written? You write "I am reading the file and displaying the array items alongside radio buttons". OK - it would help very much to see the code. What have you written, and what is the output you are getting?

Comment: Hi @Yishmeray, Sorry for that. I have add the snippet from my code for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, prime_mover! That additional detail helps. Let's assume the part down to the json_decode is right, and you've got a decoded object in the variable $jsons.
Let's put the test cases in their own variable for brevity as well.

```php
<?php
  $testCases = $jsons["testcases"];   // array of indeterminate length
?>

<form action="delete.php" method="POST">
<?php
  foreach ($testCases as $ix => $caseTxt) {
          $v = $ix+1;
?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="testcase" value="<?=$v;?>" /><?php print_r($caseTxt); echo "<br>"; ?><br>
<?php } ?>
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete Selected Values" />
</form>
```

The loop writes one new input for each entry in the $testCases array.
Not saying this is perfect code, or that it does exactly what you want to do, but it does handle a list of unknown length.

You would probably want to handle a zero length differently.

Notice I changed the type to checkbox, because your text below said "Delete Selected Values" so I guess you want to allow more than one to be selected.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Yishmeray! I didn't know PHP and HTML could be interleaved like that. Solved my problem. There were couple of syntax errors. I have suggested corrected code as an edit. Thanks again!